# cite corporate with & in name

Tags: symbols, citing

I want to cite this online research pdf made by company Bain & Company,but if I used the code down ,it convert directly to BainCompany ,the& letter is missing in the name ,how can I change my code?

```
 @misc{bain2020,
 title={Die Digitale Herausforderung }, 
 url={https://www.bain.com/contentassets/5612c973589f46cdb57853eca228b5b7/bainbrief_versicherungen_die-digitale-herausforderung_final.pdf}, 
 author={{Bain & Company}},
 year={2020}
 }
```

Comment: Use `\&`; it's in every LaTeX guide.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0):

`Bain & Company` displays [image: Bain Company] while `Bain \& Company` displays [image]. Use the `\&` character.

```tex
@misc{bain2020,
 title={Die Digitale Herausforderung }, 
 url={https://www.bain.com/contentassets/5612c973589f46cdb57853eca228b5b7/bainbrief_versicherungen_die-digitale-herausforderung_final.pdf}, 
 author={{Bain \& Company}},
 year={2020}
 }
```